# How to align lines in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I am using this [site](https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php) to write my latex equations and download them as images for my blogs. I want to write something that looks like the equation in the image on that site. How can I do that?

[image: The Latex equation I want]

This is what I have tried,

```
\\
MSE = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^2}{n}
\\
\\
(OR)$$
\\
\\
MSE = \frac{SSE}{n}
```

And it gives me this,

[image: Output]

Comment: Probably with the  `gather`  or `gathered` environment, depending on the details of what you're trying to achieve.  Could post a short, yet complete, code, and more details on what you want?

Comment: I have updated the post to show what I have tried. Plus can you suggest some tags that can be used for this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `gather` environment does not work on https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php, try this:

```
\begin{array}{c}
\mathrm{MSE}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\hat{y}_{i})^{2}}{n}\\[2mm]
\text{(OR)}\\[2mm]
\mathrm{MSE}=\frac{\mathrm{SSE}}{n}
\end{array}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! This worked on the website! Can you share a few sources from which I can learn more about LaTeX?

Comment: @Ishan Shishodiya: For example: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with `gather*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
MSE = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^2}{n}
\\[2ex]
\text{(OR)}
\\[2ex]
MSE = \frac{SSE}{n}
\end{gather*}
```

\end{document}
[image]

Comment: Your code does not work on https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php

Comment: @hair-splitter: This site doesn't have amsmath installed?

Comment: I think the editor.php does not handle the `gather` environment.

Comment: Which site did you use to write your equation?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya: My own computer. But, as far as I know, it works on Overleaf.